# How can I check whether the output strings of tail to multiple files equal each other on unix based command line?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I often use this command to append same configuration string to multiple config files.

```
>echo "delete.topic.enable = true" >> ./config/server*.properties
```

On this situation, How can I check whether I correctly append same strings to the multiple files?

```
> tail -1 config/server*.properties
==> config/server-one.properties <==
delete.topic.enable = true

==> config/server-two.properties <==
delete.topic.enable = true

==> config/server.properties <==
delete.topic.enable = true
```

I can see the result with this command. But it makes me to compare the results manually and be more hard when the string length more bigger.

I want to the results of "tail -1 *.properties" equals with one command.
I want to see only the result wether "true" or "false".

How can I do this on the command line on unix-like system?

Answer (score 1):

```
tail -q -n 1 config/server*.properties |
awk 'NR>1 && $1!=prev{multi=1; exit} {prev=$1} END{print multi+0; exit multi}'
```

The above will print 0 and exit with status 0 (success) if every line output by `tail` is identical to every other line, 1 otherwise.